# Method for storing digital security camera video

Tags: video-streaming, storage, video-capture

I have been tasked with writing an application that connects to multiple h.264 streams and stores them in a large storage array. The streams are from security cameras and thus, never ending. Obviously, I can't simply continuously dump video data into a separate file for each camera. So what are my options for storing the streams? My initial thought is to store 60 second segments that I can, according to some heuristic, periodically clean up and remove but this seems like the naive approach. Does anyone have any experience in this field and have any tips or pointers on best practices for such an application.

This is more of a conceptual question as my requirements are just on the storage and retrieval of the footage. I am platform and language agnostic.

Comment: Why invent anything complex if you can go the easy and proven ways? All car cameras work this way - they save video to SD card in chunks of configurable time.

Answer (score 0):

VCRs with time lapse capability can record for a very long time on a single tape (up to 24-48 hours). In order to fit more content on a tape, the VCR records at a slower speed and lower quality